# LaTeX Introductions in languages other than English

Tags: languages, books, tutorials, learning

Inspired by [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex), I thought that it might be useful to collect a list of the many brilliant introductory LaTeX books and tutorials written in languages other than English. I think that such a list could be helpful to many new users. And who would be better to collect such a list than the TEX.SE-community?

Please contribute to make the list as complete as possible.

Comment: No, sounds like a good question, but definitely community wiki `:)`

Comment: Should only LaTeX books be included, or are general TeX books OK?

Comment: the "not so short introduction" is available in many languages.  should they all be listed separately, under language, or would a separate answer be appropriate?  (they're all available from ctan.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton I'd say we add a category "Multilingual"or "Polyglot" at the top (ignoring the alphabetic order), perhaps with the two/three-letter abbreviations for languages as links (or only one link to http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lshort). That'll keep everything maximally clear.

Comment: Related community polls: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1595/4012, http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1571/4012

Comment: @barbara-beeton the ctan catalogue entry `lshort` provides a list of all the different translations.  i don't know if this helps (i don't know if the catalogue helps _anyone_, actually).

Answer (score 73, accepted):

***Please add your resources to this answer!***

---

### [image: globe] Multilingual

- [A Short Introduction to LaTeX2ε](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/) by Tobias Oetiker et al. (online, but also included in MiKTeX and TeX Live)
  <sup>Bulgarian, Chinese, Czech, Dutch, English, Finnish, French, German, Italian, Japanese, Korean, Mongolian, Persian, Polish, Portuguese, Brazilian Portuguese, Russian, Slovak, Slovenian, Spanish, Thai, Turkish, Ukrainian and Vietnamese.</sup>
- The [LearnLaTeX site](https://www.learnlatex.org/) is available in English, Catalan, German, Spanish, French, Marathi, Portuguese and Vietnamese; additional translations are very welcome
- [Wikibooks Latex](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX), a very nice and detailed source, is available, as ordered on said page, see left navigation column, last entries, in:
  <sub>Arabic, English, German, Spanish, French, Dutch, Polish, Russian, Turkish, Chinese, Persian, Japanese, Korean, Serbian, Indonesian, Galician, Portuguese, Romanian, Vietnamese, Czech, Hebrew, Bangla, Malayalam, Armenian.</sub>

### [image: Czech] Czech

- "Ne úplně nejkratší úvod do formátu LaTeX2ε", Czech version of "A Short Introduction to LaTeX2ε": *See above in section "Multilingual".*
- [LaTeX pro pragmatiky](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/czech/latex-pro-pragmatiky/latex-pro-pragmatiky.pdf) (2011) by Pavel Satrapa (online)

### [image: Danish] Danish

- [Introduktion til LaTeX](http://math.au.dk/videnudveksling/latex/bog/) (2011) by Lars "[daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929/daleif)" Madsen (online)
- [Latex support på DTU](http://www.latex.dtu.dk/da) (2012) by DTU students (online)

### [image: Dutch] Dutch

- "De niet zo korte inleiding tot LaTeX2ε", Dutch version of "A Short Introduction to LaTeX2ε": *See above in section "Multilingual".*
- [LateX support at Technische Universiteit Eindhoven (TU/e)](http://www.win.tue.nl/latex/) (online)
- [Een Introductie tot het Zetsysteem LaTeX](http://latex.ugent.be/cursus) (2006) by Gaspard Lequeux (online)

### Finnish

- [Käytännöllistä LaTeXia](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/info/kaytannollista-latexia/kaytannollista-latexia.pdf) (2022) by Teemu Likonen (online).

### [image: French] French

- "Une courte (?) introduction à LaTeX2ε", French version of "A Short Introduction to LaTeX2ε": *See above in section "Multilingual".*
- [Tout ce que vous avez toujours voulu savoir sur LaTeX sans jamais oser le demander](http://www.framabook.org/docs/latex/framabook5_latex_v1_art-libre.pdf) (2008) by Vincent Lozano (online, direct link)
- [LaTeX, l'essentiel](http://latex-pearson.org/) (2010) by Denis Bitouzé and Jean-Côme Charpentier (print incl. DVD, commercial)
- [La FAQ LaTeX francophone](http://faqfctt.fr.eu.org/) (ou « *La FAQ de fr.comp.text.tex* ») v3.0.alpha
- [LaTeX pour l'impatient](http://www.h-k.fr/liens/tp/latex_pour_l_impatient.html) (2009, 3rd edition) by W. Appel et al. (commercial)
- [Apprends LaTeX !](http://www.babafou.eu.org/Apprends_LaTeX/Apprends_LaTeX.pdf) (2010, 4th edition) by Marc Baudoin (online, direct link, LPPL), included in TeX Live (`texdoc apprends` should be enough to open it)
- [(Xe)LaTeX appliqué aux sciences humaines](http://geekographie.maieul.net/Xe-LaTeX-applique-aux-sciences) (2012, 1ers edition) by Maïeul Rouquette (@maïeul) for humanities. (Creative Commons, available online and buyable in print).

### [image: German] German

- [LaTeX2ε-Kurzbeschrei­bung](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/info/lshort/german/l2kurz.pdf) (2013) by [Marco Daniel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5239/marco-daniel), Patrick "[topskip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/243/topskip)" Gundlach, Walter Schmidt, Jörg Knappen, Hubert Partl and Irene Hyna, extended Ger­man ver­sion of "A Short In­tro­duc­tion to LaTeX2ε": *See above in section "Multilingual".*
- [Wissenschaftliche Arbeiten schreiben mit LaTeX: Leitfaden für Einsteiger](http://www.latexbuch.de/) (2011) by Joachim Schlosser (print/e-book; commercial)
  <sup>*A concise and well-thought-out introduction to LaTeX. The 4th edition also covers `biblatex`.*</sup>
- [Verfassen Wissenschaftlicher Texte mit LaTeX - Pep et al. Toolbox Workshop](http://toolbox.pep-dortmund.org/files/archive/latest/latex.pdf) (2015–) by *PeP et al e. V.*
  1 week introduction to modern LaTeX for physics students using `lualatex`. Focussing on a modern aproach and best practices.

  - [slides](http://toolbox.pep-dortmund.de/files/archive/latest/latex.pdf)
  - [template for lab reports](http://toolbox.pep-dortmund.de/files/archive/latest/latex-template.zip)
  - [github-repository](https://github.com/pep-dortmund/toolbox-workshop)
- [LaTeX – eine Einführung und ein bisschen mehr ...](http://www.fernuni-hagen.de/imperia/md/content/zmi_2010/a026_latex_einf.pdf) (2012) by Manuela Jürgens and Thomas Feuerstack (online, direct link)
  <sup>Refreshed classic, not in all parts up to date, though!

  *Sequel: [LaTeX – Fortgeschrittene Anwendungen, oder: Neues von den Hobbits ...](http://www.fernuni-hagen.de/imperia/md/content/zmi_2010/a027_latex_fort.pdf) (2011, direct link) by Manuela Jürgens*</sup>
- [LaTeX-Einsteiger-Kurs (Tutorial) für Ingenieure](https://manuelkuehner.de/downloads/latex-einfuehrung-tutorial-fuer-ingenieure/) (2013) by [Dr. Manuel Kuehner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14649/)
  <sup>*Focus on engineering, designed as a one-day course (~6h), with exercises.*</sup>
- [LaTeX-Einführung](http://www.matthiaspospiech.de/blog/2012/05/13/latex-einfuhrung/) (2012) by [Matthias Pospiech](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/7978/matthias-pospiech)
  <sup>*Designed as a two-day course, with exercises.*</sup>
- [Einführung in das LaTeX-Textsatzsystem](https://www.luis.uni-hannover.de/buch.html?&titel=latex) (2016, 11th edition) by [Thomas F. Sturm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/30617/thomas-f-sturm)  (print and ebook)
  <sup>*Based on a lecture on LaTeX with many examples and exercises. Available as "LUIS-Handbuch" for students at 180 public universities in Germany, Austria, and Switzerland.*</sup>
- [Schnell ans Ziel mit LaTeX2e](http://www.degruyter.com/view/product/216428) by Jörg Knappen 
  <sup>*A complete LaTeX course with special focus on mathematical typesetting. Very informative annexes with a character finder.*</sup>
- [LaTeX@TU Graz](http://latex.tugraz.at/start) (2017+) Online Pages to create a first LaTeX-document step by step.
- [LaTeX und Textsatz](https://www.mlte.de/latex/) (2013, mit jährlichen Updates bis min. 2016) 
  <sup>*LaTeX-Talk von Malte Schmitz und Johannes Thorn anlässlich der MetaNook der Uni Lübeck. 5-teiliger Einsteigerkurs mit Videos, Präsentationsfolien, LaTeX-Beispiele zum selber probieren. Geeignet für erste Schritte in LaTeX, KOMA-Script und TikZ.*</sup>
- (LaTeX. Eine Einführung](https://www.amazon.de/LATEX-Eine-Einf%C3%BChrung-Helmut-Kopka/dp/3893194347) (1994) von Helmut Kopka (print).  Not new, but reliable; suitable for learning, and also an effective reference tool after the basics are mastered.  The basis for the later English guide co-authored by Patrick Daly.

### Hungarian

- [LaTeX](https://tibortomacs.github.io/latex-tutorial-hu/latex.pdf) (2023) by Tibor Tómács (online).

### [image: Italian] Italian

- "Una (mica tanto) breve introduzione a LaTeX2ε", Italian version of "A Short Introduction to LaTeX2ε": *See above in section "Multilingual".*
- [Appunti di programmazione in TeX e LaTeX](http://profs.scienze.univr.it/%7Egregorio/introtex.pdf) (2009) by Enrico "[egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)" Gregorio (online)
- [L'Arte di scrivere con LaTeX](http://www.lorenzopantieri.net/LaTeX_files/ArteLaTeX.pdf) (2012) by Lorenzo Pantieri and Tommaso Gordini (online, direct link)
- [Introduzione all'arte della composizione tipografica con LaTeX](http://www.guitex.org/home/images/doc/guidaguit.pdf) (2012) by Claudio Beccari (coordinator) and others (online, direct link)

### [image: India] Marathi (मराठी)

- [latex-mr – A practical guide to LaTeX and Polyglossia for Marathi and other Indian languages](http://ctan.imsc.res.in/info/latex-mr/latex-mr.pdf) (2017) by Ro­hit Dilip Holkar (online, direct link)
- [लाटेक् शिका - लाटेक् ह्या उत्कृष्ट दस्तऐवजनिर्मितीसाठी वापरल्या जाणाऱ्या आज्ञावलीचे १६ सोप्या प्रकरणांतून विनामूल्य व मुक्त प्रशिक्षण.](https://www.learnlatex.org/mr/) (2021) written by team LearnLaTeX, translated by निरंजन. This is a Marathi translation of an online, interactive and [free (as in freedom)](https://freedomdefined.org/Definition#Defining_Free_Culture_Licenses) LaTeX-training website.

### [image: Norwegian] Norwegian

- [LaTeX for nybegynnere](http://dag.at.ifi.uio.no/latex-links/latex-for-nybegynnere.pdf) (2004) by Dag Langmyhr (online, direct link)
  <sup>*A little bit old, and doesn't actually mention, e.g., `pdflatex` for PDF output.*</sup>

### [image: Portuguese (Brazil)] Portuguese (Brazil)

- [Introdução ao uso do LaTeX](http://www.bookyards.com/member/ivolopez/) (2013) by Ivo Lopez and Maria Silva (online)
- [Curso de Latex](http://www.proac.uff.br/estatistica/sites/default/files/Latex_net.pdf) (2004?) by Gilberto Souto (online, direct link)
- [Uma breve introdução ao LaTeX](http://www.lce.esalq.usp.br/clarice/Paraiba.pdf) (2000) by Lenimar N. Andrade (online, direct link)

### [image: Russian] Russian

- "Не очень краткое введение в LaTeX2ε", Russian version of "A Short Introduction to LaTeX2ε": *See above in section "Multilingual".*
- [Компьютерная типография LaTeX](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/russian/Computer_Typesetting_Using_LaTeX/) (2012) by Е. М. Балдин (online)
  <sup>*Full version*</sup>
- [LaTeX в России](http://www.inp.nsk.su/%7Ebaldin/LaTeX/lurs.pdf) (2007) by Е. М. Балдин (online, direct link)
  <sup>*Short version*</sup>
- [LaTeX2ε в примерах](http://www.ccas.ru/voron/download/voron05latex.pdf) (2005) by К. В. Воронцов (online, direct link)
  <sup>*Elementary and organized introduction to LaTeX*</sup>
- [LaTeX 2e по-русски](http://www.labirint.ru/books/277560/) (2011) by [И. Котельников](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3831/igor-kotelnikov) and П. Чеботаев (print, commercial)
  <sup>[Older version (2004)](http://www.tex.uniyar.ac.ru/doc/kotelnikovchebotaev2004b.pdf) for free available for example from Yaroslavl State University (online, direct link), but see also [statement of one of the authors, Igor Kotelnikov, in TeX chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7651420#7651420)</sup>
- [TeX в ЯрГУ](http://www.tex.uniyar.ac.ru/)
  <sup>*Starter page at Yaroslavl State University*</sup>
- [Набор и верстка в системе LaTeX](http://www.mccme.ru/free-books/llang/newllang.pdf) (2003) by С. М. Львовский (online, direct link)

### [image: Serbian] Serbian

- Goran Nenadić, Predrag Janičić, Aleksandar Samardžić: [LaTeX za autore](http://knjige.kombib.rs/LaTeX2e_za_autore.html), Beograd, Kompjuter biblioteka, 2003. ("LaTeX for authors"); in Serbian only; primeri iz knjige
- Predrag Janičić, Goran Nenadić: Osnovi LaTeX-a, VEDES, Beograd, 1995. ("Fundamentals of LaTeX"); in Serbian only.

### [image: Spanish] Spanish

- "La introducción no-tan-corta a LaTeX2ε", Spanish version of "A Short Introduction to LaTeX2ε": *See above in section "Multilingual".*
- [Curso Básico de LaTeX (LaTeX Basic Course)](http://navarroj.com/latex/curso.html) (online)
- [The Wikipedia Entry (in Spanish) for LaTeX](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) (online)
  <sup>*Gives some very good first hints to people without prior knowledge, and has a very good list of links for LaTeX tutorials and manuals in spanish*</sup>
- [CervanTeX Manuals](http://www.cervantex.es/manuales)
  <sup>*Lists a number of Spanish books/tutorials on LaTeX*</sup>
- [LaTeX2e en 15 sesiones](http://www.aprendematematicas.org.mx/obras/L15.pdf) (2010) by [Efraín Soto Aguilar](http://www.aprendematematicas.org.mx/index.html) (online, direct link)
- [LaTeX 2022](https://tecdigital.tec.ac.cr/servicios/revistamatematica/Libros/LaTeX/MoraW_BorbonA_LibroLaTeX.pdf) by Alexánder Borbón A. and
  Walter Mora F. (online, direct link)

### [image: Swedish] Swedish

- [Att TeXa: en praktisk guide](http://sigurdhsson.org/latexbok/media/latexbok.pdf), 2<sup>nd</sup> ed. (2014) by Simon "[You](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/66/you)" Sigurdhsson (online, direct link)
  <sup>*[Source](https://github.com/urdh/latexbok)*</sup>
- [LaTeX-tips](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11249067/Latextips.pdf) (2012) by Niklas Andersson and [Malin Palö](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/18773/malin) (online, direct link)
- [Att skriva rapporter med LaTeX](http://www.ddg.lth.se/perf/handledning/tryck-a4.pdf) (2006) by Per Foreby (online, direct link)
- [Introduktion till LaTeX](http://libris.kb.se/bib/9416614) (2004) by Per Jacobsson (print, commercial)
  <sup>*ISBN 91-44-03314-1*</sup>

---

Public Domain flags and globe icon by [FamFamFam](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons)

Comment: Hopefully each of the TeX users group around the world (http://www.tug.org/usergroups.html)  maintain tutorials and beginners guide at their respective group websites. It may be a usefull start point for beginners.

Comment: I find it a little confusing that the most recent German introductory manual (by Manuela Jürgens and Thomas Feuerstack, 2012) still advocates the usage of `\usepackage{(n)german}` instead of the less problematic `\usepackage[(n)german]{babel}`... not to mention the used type area and table layouts.

Comment: I looked around for Hungarian resources, but all of them were outdated. When the date of creation was not available, I judged this by whether they recommended `eqnarray`.

Only one of them didn't, but that one was not suitable for introduction purposes. The first two chapters were dedicated to *nix filesystem commands, and a Vim introduction. What should I do now?

Comment: Shouldn't the first item be _A **Not So** Short Introduction to LaTeX 2e_?

Comment: @Speravir Is it really necessary/useful to add lshort in *all* languages? We sort of decided against this option in the comments to the question.

Comment: I did this in reaction to conversation with @topskip in chat. Let me link to http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9130678#9130678 There are some messages above of this, though. It started with a question by me regarding the German version already linked separately. BTW Did you notice KevinC’s comment? I thought exactly the same, but _after my edit_.

Comment: @doncherry Pinging forgotten ^^. BTW All earlier versions had set  a link separately. I thought this kind of compromise would be better.

Comment: I created fixed links with "latest" instead of the year that should always work

Comment: Just wondering – does it make any sense to keep documents which are outdated? And a second question – should broken links be removed?

Comment: Looks like some links no longer work ....

Answer (score 0):

I have taught LaTeX for beginners in Sweden (Master's and PhD students) using my compendium
[Writing science with LaTeX](https://doi.org/10.17045/sthlmuni.3205753). The teaching is in English since out MS and PhD students are international and teaching is based on using [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) and [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/) and their integration. The compendium is updated based on feedback and focuses on the typical usage in the geoscience (MS and PhD theses, downloadable templates through [Figshare](https://figshare.com/): [Undergraduate](https://doi.org/10.17045/sthlmuni.22779770) and [PhD](https://doi.org/10.17045/sthlmuni.3393655)) although it will be generally applicable to many others. Feedback is always welcome to develop content and ideas. The compendium is in English but covers multilingual use.