# How do I change the basic font into 'Corbel'?

Tags: fonts

I just started using LaTeX, so I have no clue. I have been reading stuff such as `\usepackage`, as well as things as font families. If anyone could explain me, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your question sounds as this could perhaps be useful for you: [What is the best book to start learning LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex) for English and [LaTeX Introductions in languages other than English](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84384/latex-introductions-in-languages-other-than-english). Regarding your question you should know, that for TrueType and OpenType fonts you need `fontspec` and Lua(La)TeX or Xe(La)TeX - or ConTeXt, what is another TeX dialect.

Answer (score 11):

Use `lualatex` or `xelatex` to access TrueType or OpenType fonts through the `fontspec` package.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Corbel}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just for some dummy text
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: In my eyes your example with spaces inside of the definitions was misleading for a newbie, so I made an edit.

Comment: @Jonas: you are welcome, but the best practice when a question is answered is for the person who asked the question (in this case, you) to mark the answer as accepted.  This not only provides a form of thanks, it also marks the question as effectively resolved.