# Math font in pictures of Russian math/physics textbooks

Tags: math-fonts

Does anyone know what's the font used in the following pictures? Indeed this math font is very common in many Russian math/physics textbooks published last century, and it appears in almost all the Russian math textbooks that I've read.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Sure it's not handwritten? There was some kind of standard [technical lettering](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%91%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82) before the CAD times.

Comment: Hi Oleg, thank you very much for pointing this out. I found that some books with the above fonts were published around 1970, even older than the initial release of TeX.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I'm inclined to agree with @OlegLobachev, that these diagrams were prepared by hand.  Look carefully at the two "2"s in the second image; they are very similar, but not identical, and I don't think that's the result of a low-resolution scan.  This reminds me of results obtained from using a [Leroy set](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5t1YLxb2hbY).  (That was a commonly used drafting tool in the era before computer typesetting became available.  The description linked by Oleg is the comparable tool for Cyrillic.)

Comment: OMG I forgot we had rOtring NC-scribers only as recent as 1980's (the dawn of switching from stencils to electronic lettering) pre personal word processors

Comment: @barbara beeton, thank you very much! There's a slight difference between the two "2"s, and now I believe that these letters and numbers are prepared by hand. According to [another post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88071/how-to-implement-the-russian-typographical-traditions) and [a paper](https://www.staff.uni-giessen.de/~g029/eurotex99/zaitsev.pdf), it seems that the old Russian or Soviet typographical style hasn't beem implemented hitherto. If so do you have any idea from where the original templates or stencils can be obtained?

Comment: @CeShen -- After some digging around on the web, I haven't found a source of Cyrillic templates, but I found this site with a lot more information on the use of the Leroy set: http://www.benzilla.com/?p=5433 .  Since the author appears to be very knowledgeable on the subject, I've posted an inquiry asking whether Cyrillic templates existed.  I'll report if I learn anything useful.

Comment: Look [what](https://github.com/hikikomori82/osifont) I found!

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks, indeed I'm willing to make this font via fontforge if the original templates can be found.

Comment: @OlegLobachev That osifont is interesting but is still different from this one. I'll ask the author whether he/she knows more similar font candidates.

Comment: @CeShen -- There are actually computer fonts available that are based on the Leroy styles.  And used Leroy sets are also available.  A Google search should turn up quite a few options -- but be selective!  (Good luck!)

Comment: Is this issue solved? How?