# Getting missing $ error but I don't know where to put it

Tags: errors

Newbie in LaTeX here. On this the line I'm getting "missing $" error but I don't know where exactly it wants me to put it:

```
$g_2 $= $N_2${$f_2$ - (\underbrace($\int_a^b g_1^{*}f_2dx$)_{$g_1^t\cdot f_2$} $g_1$}\\
```

Someone help?

Comment: Please post a Minimum Working Example. That is, compilable code which shows the problem. I think you are using mathematical commands outside the mathematical environment. So \underbrace, for example, is not within the scope of the $ signs yet I think it is maths (not text). The same is true of the _ between dx$) and {$g. I'm not sure what you are trying to typeset but why do you keep switching from maths to text like that?

Comment: Let $f_1\ldots$ be complete and normalized\Then take $g_i = N_1f_1$\$g_2 $= $N_2${$f_2$ - ($\int_a^b g_1^{*}f_2dx$)$g_1^t\cdot f_2$ $g_1$}\$\vdots$\$g_n = N_n { f_n - \displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{n-1}(\int_a^b g_r^* f_n dx)g_r}$\\ That's what I had before but for \int_a^b g_1^{*}f_2dx I need to put something underneath and I don't know how to do it. I was told \underbrace would work but I just kept getting $ errors.

Comment: Sorry, but this looks to me, that you lack some basic knowledge. Read an introduction to LaTeX. A (not so) “Short Introduction to LaTeX2ε” in different languages is included in all big TeX distributions. See also [What is the best book to start learning LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex) and [LaTeX Introductions in languages other than English](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84384/latex-introductions-in-languages-other-than-english).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a bit confused about what you're trying to produce here, but you've definitely split up a math expression that shouldn't be split up.

Your use of square brackets and curly brackets it a bit confusing.

Try something like (my best guess at what you meant, though I find it a bit odd):

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\[
  g_2 = N_2  f_2  - \bigg(\underbrace{\int_a^b g_1^{*}f_2dx}_{g_1^t\cdot f_2} g_1\bigg)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

`\underbrace` takes two arguments and should be written as

```
$\underbrace{<math stuff>}{<content for brace>}$
```

Or perhaps you meant:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\[
  g_2 = N_2 \bigg\{ f_2  - \underbrace{\int_a^b g_1^{*}f_2dx}_{g_1^t\cdot f_2} g_1  \bigg\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but there has to be a curly bracket after N_2 and at the end of the equation. I typed in what you did and now I have a "Missing } inserted" error.

Comment: @user42999 I've updated the answer.  LaTeX what's its braces and brackets to be balanced.  Check your code and make sure you've not forgotten a `}` or perhaps you have them improperly balanced.

Comment: @user42999 To obtain a curly bracket, you should type `\{`, `\}`, as in the example. Without it TeX thinks that they are grouping braces.

Answer (score 6):

For the version from your comment, without `\underbrace`. General rule: open math mode and stay within it through the full formula, if possible.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$g_2 = N_2{f_2 - (\int_a^b g_1^{}f_2\,dx)g_1^t\cdot f_2g_1}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Probably you want a different equality, but the general rule is clear: one opening and one closing math sign.