# Is Knuth's *The TeXBook* complete?

Tags: tex-core, knuth

Suppose I want to learn TeX. Then, is *The TeXBook* a complete source?  Does it cover all relevant aspects of TeX?  Or is there something worth learning about TeX which is not present there?

Does "TeX programming"  also appear there?

Comment: Very much depends what you want to do: it covers TeX but not LaTeX (ConTeXt, ...), only Knuth's engine (TeX90 syntax) and not specials (beyond their existence). For programming, many people like _TeX by Topic_ but as a companion to _The TeXbook_. I think we need more detail on what you want/need to do.

Comment: It depends what you want to know, that is book A in the series, you can also get a book giving the full source to tex the program and others two describing and giving the source of metafont and the computer modern fonts. If you want to know how tex is _used_ in latex or tikz etc then of course texbook says nothing.

Comment: I'm not too ambitious: I only want to be able typesetting beautiful documents (principally mathematical ones). I started first by looking at LaTeX, but I don't like very much its approach.  Then I discovered TeX and, from what I've seen, I think it is really what I'm looking for. What I mean by "programming" is the ability to manage something like variables (for example for automatically numbering theorems, referring to another page,...)

Comment: LaTeX provides macros (making a heading will always include the same steps), making it easier to use TeX. You can also check out ConTeXt. Using TeX directly is something for the *very* few chosen ones.

Comment: @user46181 plain TeX (as described in the TeXBook) is really a base example demonstration format. It specifically does _not_ have commands for higher level document use such as automatic cross referencing and numbering, although of course it describes the primitives that could enable you to write such commands.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: one thing you should take into consideration when learning a "dialect" of tex is whether you intend to publish your work, and what are the requirements of the intended publisher/publication.  plain tex allows one full freedom, but many publishers (for good reasons, largely but not completely economic) will not accept home-grown code.  that said, if you have a good grounding in the basics, and are willing to adapt later to publishers' requirements, you will gain a deeper understanding of how things work if you "start at the bottom" with the *texbook* and *tex by topic*.

Comment: Just for reference: Beside the TeXBook and [TeX by Topic](http://eijkhout.net/texbytopic/texbytopic.html) there is also [TeX for the Impatient](http://www.gnu.org/software/teximpatient/). For LaTeX see [What is the best book to start learning LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11) and [LaTeX Introductions in languages other than English](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84384) .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The TeXbook is only about `TeX` and `Plain TeX`, the program created by Knuth himself and its first format (also created by him).

It says nothing, for example, about the LaTeX or ConTeXt formats, nor about more modern engines like pdfTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX… (Nota Bene: To be allowed to exist, all those evolutions had to be named differently than TeX and/or Plain TeX.)

It remains a very useful reading if you want to learn more about how things are made at the lower levels.

Comment: Worth noting it doesn't speak about eTeX extensions.