# How to use the current value of a KOMA option?

Tags: koma-script

I want to temporarily change a KOMA option. I want to first save the current value of the option to be able to return back to it.

Comment: Which option do you want to change? Did you try to use a group?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer fontsize. I don't know how to use a group. Can you point me to some documentation where I can learn how to?

Comment: @Sinan fontsize for which element(s)? Can you please add some code to your question showing the option you intend to change and how are you doing it?

Comment: @Sinan: [What is the best book to start learning LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11) or [LaTeX Introductions in languages other than English](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84384). Or the KOMA-Script documentation depending of what you want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the fontsize is saved in `\@ptsize`:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=15pt]{scrartcl}
\makeatletter
\def\fontsizeInPT{\the\numexpr\@ptsize+10\relax pt}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
We have a fontsize of \makeatletter\@ptsize\makeatother,
which is \fontsizeInPT 
\end{document}
```

However, I do not understand why do you want to change this value. Are you looking for something like this: `\small`, `\large`  and so on?

Comment: I need this because I am trying to edit a document format created for the default font. I want the body of the text to become 12pt. However if i set 12pt globally then many hard coded pages including a very complicated title page are broken. So they have to remain at 11pt but main body of the text together with some other sections have to become 12pt.

Answer (score 0):

All KOMA-script options are described in the manual, which contains the default value as well. Let's say you were looking for parskip, you'll find that the default is `parskip=false`. If you changed the option from default to something else, and afterwards again, then it's even easier, isn't it? Go back to the line were you changed it for the first time.

Edit: According to your comment you are interested in the fontsize. See the manual: default fontsize is 11 pt.

Comment: Ok, my wording was incorrect (not a native speaker, sorry). By default, I meant the values set with `\documentclass`