# Read value of \KOMAoption for debugging purposes

Tags: koma-script, debugging

I believe that *something* in my preamble does an unwished change on a `\KOMAoption`. In order to debug the latex code, I'd like to localize the problem by dumping the current value of this `\KOMAoption`.

My approach looks like the following LaTex code, whereas I need to know the real command for `\currentValueOfKOMAoption`.

```
\document{scrreprt}
% first block of latex code
\newcommand{\thatsTheValue}{\currentValueOfKOMAoption}
% second block of latex code
\begin{document}
\thatsTheValue
\end{document}
```

---

I've already found this question on Tex.SE:

[How to use the current value of a KOMA option?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161271/how-to-use-the-current-value-of-a-koma-option)

The answer is specialized towards the fontsize. Does a generic solution exist or does the solution depend on the `\KOMAoption`? The value I'd like to track down is the `DIV`-option.

Comment: `\KOMAoptions{DIV=current}` resets with the current value.

Comment: @Manuel Thank you, I do know that and most probably this will be the bugfix. However, I'd like to find the *guilty* line of latex code.

Comment: You can find that pretty easily using the same algorithm everybody of us uses to find problems: Preparing a minimal working example. Use package `showframe` and extreme values for DIV for easier visual help. Are you using package `geometry`?

Comment: Are there any news here?