# Are there good comprehensive lists of LaTeX commands online?

Tags: learning, tutorials

I'm relatively new to actual LaTeX scripting, much of my experience comes from using MathJax over at math.stackexchange.com and I'm kinda self-taught, just picking things up as I need them. However, I'd like to write an entire paper in LaTeX now and I need to do a bit more than MathJax offers to me, such as page allignment, font selection, etc. However, it would be nice to view a list of all (or most) the commands, preferably categorized and easy to navigate. Does such a place exist and where can I find them?

Comment: Have look at `lshort.pdf`, it gives a good overview and should cover most of what you need: http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/ The wikipedia overview may be helpful if you know what you're looking for: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Command_Glossary

Comment: It is far from comprehensive, but a great start is this LaTeX cheat sheet, which I have often found useful as a quick reference: http://www.stdout.org/~winston/latex/latexsheet.pdf

Comment: There's the [command glossary in the LaTeX wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Command_Glossary), which is only really helpful if you know the name of the command, I guess.

Comment: There are books containing such overview. See [What is the best book to start learning LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11) and [LaTeX Introductions in languages other than English](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84384).

Comment: Be careful what you wish for ;). The last thing you want when starting out would be a list of *all* LaTeX commands - at least if this is understood to include all those provided by additional packages beyond the core which is LaTeX 2e itself. And you certainly wouldn't want all the LaTeX 3 stuff at that point, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t know if there is a list of *all* commands available, but there is at least the *[Comprehensive LaTeX Symbols List](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/)*. You have an exhaustive reference of mathematical and text symbols for a wide range of packages.

For the rest of the commands, the package documentations have an index of the commands defined. Maybe it is possible to parse the PDF files with a custom script which will make a more accessible list.