# Add comment/explanation at the end of the page

Tags: comments

How can I add a comment at the end of the page like this:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: This is called *foot note*: `Here comes some notes\footnote{This is the note.}`.

Comment: @PaulGessler. The solution is too simple and there are many posts here about it. Feel free to post an answer, if you wish. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That kind of note at the bottom is called a footnote. You can obtain it by

```
I say something\footnote{This is a lie.} and also something
else.\footnote{This is not a lie.}
```

Please, look at

- [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex)
- [LaTeX Introductions in languages other than English](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84384/latex-introductions-in-languages-other-than-english)

for introductory material on LaTeX.