# How to learn LaTeX in the right way?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, environments, luatex, learning

Many people always say that LaTeX is the best typesetting system which is flexible and powerful. For me, I have used LaTeX for one year already but I still have some problems with it.

Let me talk about pros and cons of LaTeX according to my experience.

**Pros**

1. LaTeX has a dynamic formatting.
2. LaTeX syntax is very simple.
3. Many packages in LaTeX make our life easier.

**Cons**

1. LaTeX has too much fragmentation in packages which also lead to fragmentation in syntax and document environments.
2. Many packages in LaTeX are not well-designed, many problems about formatting are frequently solved in a tricky way (many times via macros) instead of a straightforward way via a function parameter or option.

Usually, 50% of my working time on LaTeX is wasted on solving bug, fixing formats. This is a strong signal that tell me that I've come into the wrong way of learning and using LaTeX. Thus my questions are

> Do you agree with my complaints above? If not please explain why.
>
> What is the right way to learn LaTeX?
>
> Which packages or environments should I learn and use as a standard library?

Comment: You seem to ask a lot of questions at once, but for the one in the title see [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/35864) and maybe [LaTeX Introductions in languages other than English](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84384/35864)

Comment: All questions should lead to my main question and I also have a good resources of learning Latex but 50% of my wasting time is not about without a basic of programming in Latex but about another thing, If all questions above can be answer nicely, I think my problem should be solved.

Comment: While I'm at it, I am not sure whether I agree with your pros. (What do you mean by dynamic formatting?) And I think there are other pros, viz. good output, reasonable defaults, excellent math support. You have a point with your first con, there are lots of packages, some are no longer developed and deprecated and packages with the same aim sometimes use different commands. Your second point is not quite fair, I think most packages are actually very well designed by people who know what they are doing.

Comment: Sometime when one has to resort to trickery that is because the developer did not include the option to do that thing since it would lead to sub-par output. Some packages were created by their authors for private use and made available for the public to enjoy, so naturally features that the author didn't need don't feature that prominently.

Comment: Sorry, my english is not good. "Dynamic" I mean all elements in document can automatically rearrange and they are responsive.

Comment: Re your last point. I don't think there is a point in saying: I'm going to decide now that X, Y and Z are my "standard" packages and I will only ever use command a, environment b and c and document class e. If there is something you need to do find out what package(s) you can use, do some research (is the package superseded by a new one, deprecated ...?) and some tests (do you like the output?) and go with the one you like best. You don't actually have to know a very large set of environments and commands to write a document, you can learn while you go along.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this is just one person's opinion, but maybe it will help you understand why
latex is the way it is.

latex is a "front end" to tex.  tex is a macro language, so "problems" (think
about them instead as "how do we get the results on a page looking the way
we want them to?") are inevitably going to be "solved" with macros.  the tex
language was created by one individual, originally for his own use, and
subsequently given for free to the rest of the world in an amazingly well
documented form, with a promise to fix bugs (with a reward to the first
finder) that are found in the code or the documentation.  (and it may be
that more bugs have been found in compilers by applying them to compiling
tex than have been found in tex itself.)  after letting tex loose, its
creator returned full time to his intended life's work, completion of
his magnum opus *the art of computer programming*.

what tex is *not* is a large piece of software produced and maintained by
a large corporation.  it is a stable platform available for use by anyone
who finds a need for what it offers.

latex was also originally created by one individual, for his own use.  it
found favor among computer scientists, mathematicians, and other authors
in the "hard" sciences who found that it produced results immeasurably more
attractive (and easier to read) than what could be produced with a typewriter
or line printer.  the original author of latex has also gone on to other
pursuits, after ceding the authority to make updates to a (well qualified)
team of volunteers.

with the exception of a few small commercial enterprises, nearly all
development of packages for tex or latex has been done by volunteers, often
working alone.  there are groups of like-minded users who have banded
together into formal user groups, all of which (to my knowledge) have been
recognized as tax-exempt charities in their home countries.  there is no
"central authority" that decrees how something should be done.  (there *are*
a number of publishers who depend on (la)tex to produce their publications,
and all of these have their own rules, but there is no coordination among
them.)

packages for latex are, for the most part, created by individuals who have
particular needs, and, for the most part, "donated" to the community by
posting on ctan (another volunteer enterprise).  many, if not most, package
authors welcome feedback and bug reports, but writing packages is not their
key occupation, and life has a habit of getting in the way.

so, back to your comments.  yes, latex is fragmented, and isn't likely to
become any more unified, at least not in my lifetime.  all that can be hoped
for is that package authors pay more attention to "best practices", current
conventions (which do change over time), and the quality of their user
documentation.  they can also communicate with other package authors and
users (good places are through the above-mentioned user groups, and forums
such as this one) to try to approach "problems" in a consistent manner.  but
individuals are individuals, and "controlling" them is somewhat like herding cats.

as for "the best way" to learn latex, i recommend starting with a good book.
my favorites are kopka & daly, and gratzer's "more math into latex".  for
special situations, the several "companions" are solid, if likely to become
dated.  start with the basic document classes -- `article`, `book` and `proc` -- and explore other approaches as well: the ams classes, classes
in the `koma` bundle, `memoir`; all have valuable, and different, points
of view.  ask questions here when you run into a thorny patch, but be sure
to say what you've done and provide an example that demonstrates the problem
to give a helper a solid place to start debugging.

and don't give up.