# How do I reduce the size of the word "References" in the bibliography section?

Tags: bibliographies, fontsize

I'm using `\begin{thebibiliography}` to generate a bibliography at the end of the page. The heading for this is "References" and I would like to reduce the size of this heading. I'm using the article document class.

Comment: Maybe the `titlesec` package could do the job.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Knowing the document class you're using is necessary.

Comment: Could you please help me with titlesec and how I could go about doing this?

Comment: Try the  light version, if you only want to change the size of the references title: `\titleformat*{\section}{\large}` (the default in the article class is `\Large`).

Comment: Oh thanks! Any suggestions on how I can make it bold face too?

Comment: Add `\bfseries` to @Bernard's comment: `\titleformat*{\section}{\large\bfseries}`. If you are new to LaTeX, you may find [these answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/8528) (and, for languages other than English, [these answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84384/8528)) helpful.

Comment: @Bernard Do you want to write up an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to go is the light usage of `titlesec`. As in the article class, the bibliography is a `\section`, which by default is in `\Large` size,  you can add this to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\bfseries\large}
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Padkoi ;o)