# How to work out as in picture!

Tags: tables, equations, align, subequations

Can you show me how to work out as in picture? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is a do-it-for-me question. Please show us what you've got so far (MWE).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `aligned` from the `amsmath` package.  You seem to struggle with the very basics of LaTeX.  Therefore please also see these two questions:

- [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11)
- [LaTeX Introductions in languages other than English](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84384)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    -\Delta u &= \mu p(x,u), && x \in \Omega \\
    u &= 0, && x \in \partial\Omega,
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]