# Commands and Text don't show up in PDF(new to Latex)

Tags: pdftex

[image: PDF and Code side by side]

Hi I'm new to Latex and tried to teach myself. I use the Texmaker and Miktex for windows 10. However my PDF viewer only shows the PDF I've compiled and not any changes I make to the code. additionally the compiled PDF does not correspond entirely to the code I wrote. I do not know where the 1 in the PDF is coming from and my Title, author and date are missing.

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917). The title/author comes out only after issuing `\maketitle` in the document, and the 1 you are seeing is produced by `\thanks`, which basically makes a footnote. Please give a look at [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/82917) and [LaTeX Introductions in languages other than English](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84384/82917).

Comment: TeXmaker doesn't compile on-the-fly like `gummi` or TeXpad does. Therefore changes are only seen after a recompilation of your document. Also, if you use a PDF viewer that does not support `SyncTeX` you won't see changes either. you're more likely to get a warning or error, that the PDF couldn't be written on (that happens with PDF viewers such as Adobe, PDF Xchange, Foxit, etc. which lock the file. Use SumatraPDF instead. The internal viewer should show changes almost immediately after compiling.)

Comment: @naphaneal Using `synctex` has nothing whatsoever to do with whether the file is redisplayed when it changes. It is used for synchronisation of locations in the output with locations in the input.

Comment: @cfr I never said nor intended to imply that. There are however, certain features available in SumatraPDF, e.g.  SyncTeX synchronization, pdfsync, etc., that allow for (almost) instant review of changes in a recompiled PDF. Most PDF viewers I know of are missing such support.

Comment: @naphaneal You said 'Also, if you use a PDF viewer that does not support SyncTeX you won't see changes either.' That is simply false.