# How to write L_{1} within a textit{} function

Tags: math-mode

Im trying to write  L_{1} in a \textit{} function.

```
\textit{L_{1}}
```

But this just gives me
[image]

How can I make it (ignore the overline): [image]

Comment: Is $L_1$ what you look for?

Comment: That's a very simple task.  I recommend you read one of the many resources listed under [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11) or if English is not your first language see [LaTeX Introductions in languages other than English](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84384).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the math mode.

```
$\mathit{L_1}$
```

or

```
$L_1$
```